# How can I achieve this a slide effect like this in Javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi I'm a JS and CSS newbie and was wondering if anyone knows how this effect can be created.

http://www.cloudbees.com/

Comment: Look at the source code.

Comment: ITs called parallax scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have said, this effect is known as Parallax Scrolling. There are a number of different plugins but I've found that personally the best one is Skrollr.js which you can find [here](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) (scroll to the bottom to find the GitHub link)